# Performance testing a service using ICAP

Tags: java, performance-testing, microservices, icap

I am trying to performance test a service that uses ICAP as its protocol. Is there any specific tool / library that can come in handy? Any Java suggestions?

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tools that can directly test ICAP.

However, you can test it indirectly by "web performance tester", via a compliant proxy, by generating the same traffic that a browser would generate through the proxy, which in turn talks ICAP to the service.

Ali